# using count() but unable to get the correct output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a tic tac toe game in python and at this stage i am finding a horizontal winner . Everything in the program is currently hard coded .
According to the game list right now the first row should be the winner , but the output is wrong .

i was trying to iterate over each element in the row , but then encountered this count(), but it doesn't seem to work

```
game=[[1,1,1],
      [0,2,0],
      [2,2,0 ]]

def win(current_game):
    for row in current_game:
        print(row)
        if (row.count(row[0]==len(row))==True):
            print("winner", row[0])

win(game)
```

the output i got is :-

```
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 0]
winner 2
```

but the correct output should be :-

```
[1,1,1]
winner 1
[0,2,0]
[2,2,0]
```

Comment: In a tic-tac-toe, there's only two digits, usually 1 and 0 (or X and O). What's this 2 for? How do you decide who is the winner?

Comment: I think 0 is when we haven't made a X or an O in the tic-tac-toe

Comment: 0 is the initial value.. and 1 and 2 are the numbers used by player 1 and player 2 respectively for the game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding, `row.count(obj)` returns how many times `obj` occurs in your `row` object. [Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm)

So, `row[0]==len(row)` being a comparison and returning either `true` or `false` doesn't make sense here. With `row.count(row[0]==len(row))` you are checking if `true` or `false` occurs in `row` and not a number.

What you want is to check if your first item in your list occurs three times (or whichever length the list is).

```py
def win(current_game):
    for row in current_game:
        print(row)
        if (len(row) == row.count(row[0])):
            print("winner", row[0])
```

Comment: @simrangupta If my answer helped you solve your problem, I'd appreciate it, if you accept it by clicking on the check mark. 